# How do you use a for each loop with pointers and polymorphism?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am trying to create a bank account program with persistence that uses inheritance and polymorphism.
I have an Account class with Savings and Checking classes inheriting from it. This loop in my main is supposed to write the data of each object in my vector of Account pointers to a file. I use my writeData (savings and checking writeData functions override the Account write data function) function in a for each loop

```
    for each(Account* acc in myAccounts)
    {
        acc.writeData(file);
        count++;
        if (count != myAccounts.size())
        {
            file << "\n";
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error

```
error C2228: left of '.writeData' must have class/struct/union
```

When I try to add a class type (Account acc.writeData(file);) it says it expected a semicolon after the acc

I cant figure out how to fix this

Comment: Please post some code.  Preferably an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `acc` is a pointer *to* an object, so unless I'm mistaken, you would need `acc->writeData(file);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax if you are using MS VS

```
for each(Account* acc in myAccounts)
{
    acc->writeData(file);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    count++;
    if (count != myAccounts.size())
    {
        file << "\n";
    }
}
```

or the following otherwise (new MS VS(s) also support it)

```
for (Account* acc : myAccounts)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
{
    acc->writeData(file);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    count++;
    if (count != myAccounts.size())
    {
        file << "\n";
    }
}
```

Also it is not clear why there is no statement `file << "\n";` for the last item. Are you sure that you do not want just to write

```
for (Account* acc : myAccounts)
{
    acc->writeData(file);
    file << "\n";
}
```